# Evaluating $\int_0^y \frac{z^2e^{az}}{e^z-1}\,\mathrm dz$.

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, zeta-functions, bernoulli-numbers

> Given $a,y\in\mathbb{C}$, I want to find a closed form for
> $$
> \int_0^y \frac{z^2e^{az}}{e^z-1}\,\mathrm dz.
> $$

**Background:**

This integral was obtained from an infinite sum involving Bernoulli number and I want to simplify it. I noticed using wxMaxima software that it has a closed form for $a=1$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ in terms of the polylogarithm, but I have not been able to find such an expression for another $a$.

Such integral comes from the following:
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $B_n$ denote the $n$-th Bernoulli numbers, which can be defined as
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{B_n}{n!}(x).$$
For some $x,w\in\mathbb{C}$ I want to take the limit
$$\lim_{\Re(w)\to\infty}e^w\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{B_n}{n!}(-x)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{w^k}{k!}.$$
Substituting a known formula I found on [Uniform Convergence Behavior of the Bernoulli Polynomials, John Mangual](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703452.pdf) page 2
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{w^k}{k!} = \int_0^w z^{n+1}e^z dz,$$
related to a Gábor Szegő's paper in 1928, then gives
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{B_n}{n!}(-x)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{w^k}{k!}
= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{B_n}{n!}(-x) \int_0^w z^{n+1}e^z dz 
= \int_0^w \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} z \frac{B_n}{n!}(-xz)^{n}e^z dz
\\
= \int_0^w z\frac{-xz}{e^{-xz}-1} e^z dz
$$
Finally the main integral comes after the change of variable $z' = \frac{z}{-x}.$

Comment: According to Mathematica: $I(a,y)=2 \zeta (3,a)-e^{a y} \left(-2 y \Phi \left(e^y,2,a\right)+2 \Phi \left(e^y,3,a\right)+y^2
   \Gamma (a) \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(1,a;a+1;e^y\right)\right)$.  I'm sure this could be worked out with integral definitions of these functions and possibly integration by parts.

Comment: If you include more context to your question so it meets the quality standards of MSE I may be able to derive this.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I am not used to Mathematica so I do not understand your formula. Please let me know what are $I(a,y)$ (the integral?), $\Phi$ (Lerch transcendent zeta function?) and $\tilde{F}$ (?). I only recognize $\Gamma$ as the well-known gamma function. I also do not understand what do you mean by "quality standards of MSE". Do you want me to include how I derived this from an infinite sum involving Bernoulli numbers?

Comment: Yes. Please include a summary of how you derived this from the infinite sum as to give this problem context and meet the quality standards of the site.  Also, $I(a,y)$ is your integral, $\tilde F$ is the regularized hypergoemetric function, and $\Phi$ is the [Lerch Transcendent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HurwitzLerchPhi.html).

Comment: Good. I already added how this comes from an infinite sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
I(a,y)=\int_0^y \frac{z^2e^{az}}{e^z-1}\,\mathrm dz.
$$
We will first perform integration by parts with $u=z^2$ and $\mathrm dv=e^{az}/(e^z-1)\,\mathrm dz$. Clearly, $\mathrm du=2 z\,\mathrm dz$ so we write
$$
\begin{align}
v &=\int \frac{e^{az}}{e^z-1}\,\mathrm dz\\
&\overset{x=e^z}{=}-\int\frac{x^{a-1}}{1-x}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=-\int_0^x\frac{w^{a-1}}{1-w}\,\mathrm dw\\
&\overset{w=tx}{=}-x^a\int_0^1\frac{t^{a-1}}{1-xt}\,\mathrm dt.
\end{align}
$$
Comparing with [DLMF 15.6.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E1) and reintroducing $x=e^z$ yields
$$
v=-\frac{1}{a}e^{az}F(1,a;1+a;e^z),
$$
such that
$$
I(a,y)=-\frac{1}{a}z^2e^{az}F(1,a;1+a;e^z)\bigg|_{z=0}^y+\frac{2}{a}\underbrace{\int_0^yze^{az}F(1,a;1+a;e^z)\,\mathrm dz}_{J(a,y)},
$$
where $F(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z)$ is the [Gauss hypergeometric function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15). The limit as $z\to 0$ is zero which is due to $F(1,a;1+a;e^z)\sim-a\log(1-e^z)$, c.f. [DLMF 15.4.21](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4.E21), and $\lim_{z\to 0} z\log(1-e^z)=0$. Hence,
$$
I(a,y)=-\frac{1}{a}y^2e^{ay}F(1,a;1+a;e^y)+\frac{2}{a}J(a,y).
$$

Our next task is to determine $J(a,y)$. As before we will use integration by parts with $u=z$ and $\mathrm dv=e^{az}F(1,a;1+a;e^z)\,\mathrm dz$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
v &=\int e^{az}F(1,a;1+a;e^z)\,\mathrm dz\\
&\overset{x=e^z}{=}\int x^{a-1}F(1,a;1+a;x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^x w^{a-1}F(1,a;1+a;w)\,\mathrm dw\\
&\overset{w=xt}{=}x^a\int_0^1 t^{a-1}F(1,a;1+a;xt)\,\mathrm dt.
\end{align}
$$
Comparing with [DLMF 16.5.2](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.5.E2) and again reintroducing $x=e^z$ gives
$$
v=\frac{1}{a}e^{az}{_3F_2}\left({1,a,a\atop 1+a,1+a};e^z\right),
$$
and
$$
J(a,y)=\frac{1}{a}ze^{az}{_3F_2}\left({1,a,a\atop 1+a,1+a};e^z\right)\bigg|_{z=0}^y-\frac{1}{a}\int_0^ye^{az}{_3F_2}\left({1,a,a\atop 1+a,1+a};e^z\right)\,\mathrm dz,
$$
where ${_pF_q}(\mathbf a;\mathbf b;z)$ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16). The limit at zero presents no problems this time and so we evaluate the limit term by direct substitution. With the help of [this identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.06.03.0060.01) we then write the ${_3F_2}(\cdot)$ function in terms of the [Lerch transcendent](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/LerchPhi/), $\Phi(z,s,a)$, and subsequently obtain
$$
J(a,y)=aye^{ay}\Phi(e^y,2,a)-a\int_0^ye^{az}\Phi(e^z,2,a).
$$
To tidy things up a bit we substitute the current form of $J(a,y)$ into $I(a,y)$ and write
$$
I(a,y)=-\frac{1}{a}y^2e^{ay}F(1,a;1+a;e^y)+2ye^{ay}\Phi(e^y,2,a)-2\underbrace{\int_0^ye^{az}\Phi(e^z,2,a)}_{J^\ast(a,y)}.
$$
Our last task is to find $J^\ast(a,y)$. Substituting $t=e^z$ gives
$$
J^\ast(a,y)=\int_1^{e^y}t^{a-1}\Phi(t,2,a)\,\mathrm dt.
$$
The antiderivative of the integral is given [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.06.21.0002.01) yielding
$$
\begin{align}
J^\ast(a,y)
&=t^a\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^k}{(k+a)^3}\bigg|_{t=1}^{e^y}\\
&=t^a\Phi(t,3,a)\bigg|_{t=1}^{e^y}\\
&=e^{ay}\Phi(e^y,3,a)-\Phi(1,3,a)\\
&=e^{ay}\Phi(e^y,3,a)-\zeta(3,a),
\end{align}
$$
where $\zeta(s,a)$ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta2/). Substituting $J^\ast$ into $I$ then gives the final result
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{%
I(a,y)=2\zeta(3,a)+2e^{ay}(y\Phi(e^y,2,a)-\Phi(e^y,3,a))-\frac{1}{a}y^2e^{ay}F(1,a;1+a;e^y).%
}
$$

Here is the Mathematica code for ploting the result:

```
Int[a_, y_] := 
  2 HurwitzZeta[3, a] + 
   2 E^(a y) (y HurwitzLerchPhi[E^y, 2, a] - 
      HurwitzLerchPhi[E^y, 3, a]) - 
   1/a y^2 E^(a y) Hypergeometric2F1[1, a, 1 + a, E^y];
Plot[{Int[1, y], Int[2, y], Int[3, y]}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

...and the plot it produces:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! how in hell you did it? It will take some time for me to understand all steps. Still I'm not getting what $F(a', b;c;d)$ is, please help us write down here its definition(s), since at my sight it is very similar to the very first integral we wanted in terms of other special functions like exponential integrals or zeta functions.
(for instance there's an errata in the second equation $v=\int\cdots$: an extra $z^2$ in the numerator, which corresponds to $u$, would you kindly fix it?)

Comment: @DrPotato Good catch on the extra $z^2$! If you are happy with the answer please don't forget to upvote and accept it. A lot of the steps here is just basic integration by parts, substitutions, and then just knowing properties about these special functions and how they're related.  If you click on the links in the answer it will take you to webpages where you can find definitions and additional information about the functions used.  For example, $F(\cdots)$ is the ${_2F_1}$ hypergeometric function and you can find info for it in the link provided.

Comment: @DrPotato You can also evaluate the solution for specific values of $a$ and $y$ in WolframAlpha by clicking [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+HurwitzZeta%5B3%2C+a%5D%2B2+E%5E%28a+y%29+%28y+HurwitzLerchPhi%5BE%5Ey%2C+2%2C+a%5D-HurwitzLerchPhi%5BE%5Ey%2C+3%2C+a%5D%29-1%2Fa+y%5E2+E%5E%28a+y%29+Hypergeometric2F1%5B1%2C+a%2C+1+%2B+a%2C+E%5Ey%5D+for+a%3D1+and+y%3D1) (You will have to scroll to end of input bar in WA to change values).

Comment: Of course I will upvote once I fully understand it!
As you can see in the background of the description, I am taking also $\lim_{\Re(w)\to\infty}$.. if you think you can also help me with this I can post another question and you (or anyone) could get another upvote :D

Comment: @DrPotato Of course you can post your follow up question in a new post. I know I mentioned the MSE quality standards, which the moderators are really beginning to enforce. So before you post another question see [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hi stranger ! Once more, *brillantissimo* ! Cheers and thanks for posting answers of such quality !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for stopping by Claude! Cheers :)